# How can I make this plot easier to see?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

How can I make this plot easier to see? In this plot the waverform is not clear.
If I plot with `w` only from `0` to `1000` it is better but I wonder if there is a way to see in a wider range.

```
result = LaplaceTransform[
   a + ((b - a)/tr t - (b - a)/tr t0) (UnitStep[t - t0] - 
       UnitStep[t - (t0 + tr)]) + (b - a) UnitStep[t - (t0 + tr)], t, 
   s];
freq[a_, b_, t0_, tr_, s_] := Evaluate@result;
LogLinearPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs@ExpToTrig@freq[2, 3, 10, #, I*w] & /@ 
   Range[ 1 10^-9, 1 10^-6, 10^-7]], {w, 0, 10^9}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Range[10], PlotPoints -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to show? Perhaps `LogLogPlot` would work better.

Comment: @BobHanlon I want to check how `tr` changes frequency range. I just tried `LogLogPlot` but it doesn't look good either.

Comment: You have to plot over a very narrow domain, or you'll get a mess. E.g., `{w, 9*10^6, 9.000002*10^6}` or `{w, 9*10^8, 9.00000002*10^8}`. To check dependence on `tr`, perhaps `Simplify[Abs@ExpToTrig@freq[2, 3, 10, tr, I*w], 1 10^-9 < tr < 1 10^-6] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify` is sufficiently simple to analyze.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

It would be preferable if you limited the number of functions being displayed to one or at most two. You can do this with [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

freq[a_, b_, t0_, tr_, s_] = 
  LaplaceTransform[
    a + ((b - a)/tr t - (b - a)/tr t0) (UnitStep[t - t0] - 
        UnitStep[t - (t0 + tr)]) + (b - a) UnitStep[t - (t0 + tr)], t, s] // 
   Simplify;

trRng = Range[10^-9, 10^-6, 10^-7];

funcs = Simplify@ComplexExpand@Abs@
       freq[2, 3, 10, #, I*w] & /@ trRng;
```

To selectively display the functions:

```
Manipulate[
 If[sel === {}, sel = {1}];
 pltType[Evaluate@funcs[[sel]], {w, 0, 10^9},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[sel]],
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[
    ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[sel]],
    N[10^7*trRng[[sel]]],
    LegendLabel -> Style[#, 12, Bold] &@
     StringForm["`` * tr", Superscript[10, 7]]],
  PlotPoints -> 200, (* flavor to taste *)
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  ImageSize -> Medium],
 {{pltType, LogLinearPlot, 
   Style["Plot type", 12]}, {LogLinearPlot -> LogLinear, 
   LogLogPlot -> LogLog}},
 Delimiter,
 {{sel, {1}, Style[#, 12] &@
    StringForm["`` * tr", Superscript[10, 7]]}, 
  Thread[Range[10] -> N[10^7 trRng]], ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]
```

[image]

Note that when displaying more than one function, you can move a function to the front by unchecking and then rechecking the box for that function.